# Is it bad to leave the lever in preinfusion mode for a long time?

Tags: espresso-machine, maintenance

We have a Rocket Espresso Milano at the office. Recently, I have often found the machine with the lever in the middle position (preinfusion). I guess some people don't turn it all the way down after use.

If it's not harmful for the machine, then I can just let it go, but if it's bad for the machine (or if it impacts the coffee quality for the next user) then I might have to paste a note to let people know not to do that.

Any insights? Thanks!